# How to get a testing http request in django testcase?

Tags: django, forms, testcase

I'm working in a solution with only an GraphQL API, so all my logic are in forms. The save method of one of my forms receives the http request. I use the request to get some data for mailing. So, I'm trying to make a test case of this form but I don't know how to pass the request object.

```py
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
  ...
  def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

How can I pass the request object to form in a test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate HttpRequest and use it as a regular request in your test:

```
    fake_request = HttpRequest()
    fake_request.user = AnonymousUser()
    fake_request.META['SERVER_NAME'] = site.domain
    fake_request.META['SERVER_PORT'] = 80

    s = SessionStore()
    s.create()
    fake_request.session = s
```

In your case you might need to fill more fields

Comment: Perfect answer, Thank you so much.